# Obscure trait bound error when trying to insert a value on a table (Diesel)

Tags: rust, rust-diesel

I'm trying to make Diesel work, and for testing purposes, I made a "Book" table and entity, ran the migration, and then actually tried to create the "createBook" function. For a SQLite server, it looks like this:

```
use diesel::prelude::*;
use crate::models::Book;
use crate::schema::books;
use crate::db;


pub fn create_book(book: &Book) -> Book {
    let mut connection: SqliteConnection = db::establish_connection();
    diesel::insert_into(books::table)
        .values(book)
        .get_result(&mut connection)
        .expect("Error saving new post")
}
```

At the `.get_result(&mut connection)` part, I get a huge error regarding trait bounds, that I don't really understand:

```
{unknown}
the trait bound `diesel::query_builder::returning_clause::ReturningClause<(columns::book_id, columns::title, columns::author, columns::creation_date, columns::publishing_house, columns::release_date, columns::cover_image)>: QueryFragment<Sqlite, backend::sql_dialect::returning_clause::DoesNotSupportReturningClause>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `QueryFragment<DB, SP>`:
  <diesel::query_builder::returning_clause::ReturningClause<Expr> as QueryFragment<DB, backend::sql_dialect::returning_clause::PgLikeReturningClause>>
  <diesel::query_builder::returning_clause::ReturningClause<Expr> as QueryFragment<DB, sqlite::backend::SqliteReturningClause>>
  <diesel::query_builder::returning_clause::ReturningClause<Expr> as QueryFragment<DB>>
required because of the requirements on the impl of `QueryFragment<Sqlite>` for `diesel::query_builder::returning_clause::ReturningClause<(columns::book_id, columns::title, columns::author, columns::creation_date, columns::publishing_house, columns::release_date, columns::cover_image)>`
1 redundant requirement hidden
required because of the requirements on the impl of `QueryFragment<Sqlite>` for `InsertStatement<table, diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::ValuesClause<(DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::book_id, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, &i32>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::title, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::author, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::creation_date, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::publishing_house, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::release_date, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::cover_image, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, &std::string::String>>>), table>, diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::private::Insert, diesel::query_builder::returning_clause::ReturningClause<(columns::book_id, columns::title, columns::author, columns::creation_date, columns::publishing_house, columns::release_date, columns::cover_image)>>`
required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<'_, diesel::SqliteConnection, _>` for `InsertStatement<table, diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::ValuesClause<(DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::book_id, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, &i32>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::title, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::author, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::creation_date, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::publishing_house, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::release_date, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::cover_image, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, &std::string::String>>>), table>>`rustcE0277
mod.rs(1679, 15): required by a bound in `get_result`
the trait bound `(i32, std::string::String, std::string::String, std::string::String, std::string::String, std::string::String, std::string::String): FromStaticSqlRow<(diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>), Sqlite>` is not satisfied
the following other types implement trait `FromStaticSqlRow<ST, DB>`:
  <(T0,) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST0,), __DB>>
  <(T1, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST0), __DB>>
  <(T1, T2, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST0), __DB>>
  <(T1, T2, T3, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST0), __DB>>
  <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST0), __DB>>
  <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST0), __DB>>
  <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST0), __DB>>
  <(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6, T7, T0) as FromStaticSqlRow<(ST1, ST2, ST3, ST4, ST5, ST6, ST7, ST0), __DB>>
and 24 others
required because of the requirements on the impl of `FromSqlRow<(diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>), Sqlite>` for `Book`
required because of the requirements on the impl of `load_dsl::private::CompatibleType<Book, Sqlite>` for `(diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>)`
required because of the requirements on the impl of `LoadQuery<'_, diesel::SqliteConnection, Book>` for `InsertStatement<table, diesel::query_builder::insert_statement::ValuesClause<(DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::book_id, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, &i32>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::title, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::author, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Text, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::creation_date, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::publishing_house, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::release_date, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, &std::string::String>>>, DefaultableColumnInsertValue<ColumnInsertValue<columns::cover_image, diesel::internal::derives::as_expression::Bound<diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, &std::string::String>>>), table>>`rustcE0277
models.rs(7, 10): required because of the requirements on the impl of `diesel::Queryable<(diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>, diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Text>), Sqlite>` for `Book`
mod.rs(1679, 15): required by a bound in `get_result`
```

Can someone give an explanation on what these errors mean?

I wonder if this has anything to do with how I deal with entities. I chose to use only one entity struct both for retrieving and saving (which doesn't seem to be the default way for Diesel), and maybe there's the problem. Any ideas?

```
use diesel::prelude::*;
use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};    
use crate::schema::books;

#[derive(Queryable, Serialize, Deserialize, Insertable)]
#[diesel(table_name = books)]
pub struct Book {
    pub book_id: i32,
    pub title: String,
    pub author: String,
    pub creation_date: String,
    pub publishing_house: String,
    pub release_date: String,
    pub cover_image: String
}
```

Comment: The key part of the error is `the trait bound \`(i32, std::string::String, std::string::String, ...): FromStaticSqlRow<(diesel::sql_types::Nullable<diesel::sql_types::Integer>, diesel::sql_types::Text, diesel::sql_types::Text, ...), Sqlite>\` is not satisfied`. Your model struct doesn't match your schema. Nullable columns need the corresponding struct fields to be `Option<_>`.

But aside from that, the primary key should probably not be nullable, and I'm pretty sure there's some features in diesel where it's useful to have the PK called `id` instead of `book_id`.

Comment: @michalwa Thank you for your input! I'll look forward to this and tell you my findings.

Comment: any news about this ? i'm having same issue

Comment: @modex98 the fix that the michalwa suggested works well!

Comment: @michalwa consider making your own answer, since it worked pretty well for me